# Differences between Official and Community documentation?

Tags: documentation

Ubuntu provides [Official](https://help.ubuntu.com/) and [Community](https://help.ubuntu.com/community) documentation.

- Why create the two streams?
- Is the official documentation more trustworthy?
- Is the criteria to add to it more strict?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Community documentation can be created by anyone using the wiki.
- Any user can create a **how-to** for any ubuntu-related topic under the Community documentation.
- Official documentation are the online html version of the system documentation that can be edited only by core-doc team.
- The official documentation are narrower in scope,dealing only with main help topics.